# Multiple Updates on Different Subsets of SQL Server Table Causing Deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, deadlock, data-warehouse

I have a data warehouse that essentially has the data of 8 or 9 companies all rolled up into the same tables. There are SSIS jobs for each company that are running (sometimes simultaneously) and  updating different subsets of the same tables which occasionally causes a deadlock. I've also got SSAS models that are selecting data out of these tables while they are being updated for different companies by different SSIS ETL jobs.

There's a int field in every table to indicate which company the data is for and while the same table may be updated multiple times simultaneously, it's *never* updating the same rows as another job. How do I prevent the deadlocks?

If I were to partition every table (one partition for each company) and change the lock escalation to auto, will that prevent deadlocks? Seems like it's working in my tests but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Thank you

Comment: The only way to know how you might attempt to avoid deadlocks is by inspecting the deadlock graph and seeing which resources are conflicting. But its virtually impossible to completely avoid deadlocks, so you usually need a retry mechanism as well.

Comment: Jut curious, If each SSIS job is updating rows that do not conflict with another job process how does deadlock occur

Comment: Yes, partitioning *can* avoid these kind of deadlocks, but so can indexing with the `int` column first, partitioning is not necessary per se. We need to see the deadlock graph, the query plans and the table/index definitions to know for sure what the problem is

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Pretty easy if there is no index or partitioning on that column, you get full table scans which lock up a lot of rows.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph I believe what's happening is that one package is running an update on the Payment table for SourceKey = 15 and another job is running the same package for SourceKey = 18 on the Payment table and SQL Server is choosing to do a table lock and it gets deadlocked.

Comment: understood, so lock escalation resulting in table deadlocks